# References in PHP

Tags: php

I know that using & before a function's parameter means it's passed by reference, and can be used for output, but what does it mean if I use it in another context?

For example:

```
function foo (&$param) {
    $param = 3;
}

foo (&$a);
echo $a;
```

I added the & when calling foo just to see what happens, and it didn't actually appear to change anything, and $a isn't even defined before that point.

Could anyone please explain that?

Comment: @DaveRandom that should be an answer because it is exactly what OP needed.

Comment: @Matt Fair point, I'll move it.

Comment: After reading such question I always slightly confused: "I know that using & before a function's parameter means it's passed by reference, and can be used for output, [..]" Why don't you use `return $value` to return a value? Why you even consider using references instead?!

Comment: @KingCrunch Might be just a bad C++ habit, I'm pretty new to PHP... but often enough I have to return more than one value. Also I often return true/false for success/failure and try to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 7):

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) says:

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use `&` in `foo(&$a);`.

Further to this, as of 5.4.0 you will actually get a parse error. Before that it will work but since 5.3 it will complain about. Since there are some native functions that actually *require* call-time pass-by-reference (for example [`debug_zval_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) and underneath `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()`) this aspect of 5.4 degrades *badly*.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to a comment while I was posting an answer. +1 good sir :)

Comment: @Fluffeh I shall reciprocate for your troubles, since all I did is basically regurgitate the manual. It has seriously annoyed me that they have made call time pass by reference a parse error and not fixed `debug_zval_dump()` though - I mean yes it still *works* but what good is it without a useful refcount? You might as well just `var_dump()`

Comment: Can you elaborate where you *need* call-time pass-by-reference? `array()` comes to mind, but it's not a real function and it still seems to work in 5.4.

Comment: @phant0m The option of being able to call a function by `$someVar=someFunction($myVar)` as compared to `someFunction(&$myVar)` is missed. Sometimes you want to have your variable changed by a function without explicitly saying `$someVar=someFunction($someVar);` It's a pain in the ass.

Comment: @phant0m `debug_zval_dump()` actually requires you to pass a reference in order to get a sensible refcount value otherwise you just get `1` because you passed in a copy. There is a note in the manual for [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) that has actually changed since the last time I read it about how it used to pass by reference and now it doesn't, which is even *more* confusing than it was.

Comment: 5.4 *needed* to break.  Call-time pass-by-reference was already a broken idea from the start.  "You mean, i can pass this thing by reference without the function knowing about it?  And whatever changes are made to the arg, that'd normally be private and fine, are now visible parts of my API?"  No.  That should never have existed.

Comment: @cHao No arguments from me there, but I do think they should have fixed builtins that relied on it before removing it. I know there's another one I've come across before but right now for the life of me I can't remember what it is.

Comment: @Fluffeh I don't see how that relates to my question.

Comment: @phant0m It means you have to specify in the function whether it is changing the variable, or returning a different one rather than being able to do so in the way you call the function. A function can no longer be able to do both. It either changes the variable you pass, or it returns a different one - not both.

Comment: @DaveRandom I see, that is certainly interesting. Any ideas why they could have opted not to change `debug_zval_dump()`'s signature to pass-by-reference? Or is it simply an oversight?

Comment: The `debug_zval_dump` issue doesn't seem like a big one to me.  PHP basically assigns by cloning references + COW anyway, far as i've seen.  So, you pass a regular old variable and subtract 1 from the number returned.  What am i missing?

Comment: @phant0m My guess is they just forgot. I imagine it's regarded as a pretty rarely used debugging function - although it does have a potentially useful application if it worked properly.

Comment: @cHao It would potentially be useful for determining if two variables of primitive types (basically anything that's not an object) were references to each other. I know this is not something one needs to do particularly often, but without being able to inspect the zval the only way to do it is to modify one value and see if the other changes - whereas what would be better would be create a new reference and see if the refcount increases since this doesn't modify the variable, avoiding the [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).

Comment: @DaveRandom: The larger problem is that PHP implemented references without a way to tell if two references are to the same primitive.  You shouldn't even need to call debug functions to do such a basic thing; it should be built into the language.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `&$param` in a function it mean you pass by reference. You however shouldn't use it in the function call - with current versions of PHP, this will generate a warning. Function calls are only allowed to pass a variable now. The function declaration must be indicative of whether the function accepts the argument by reference or by passing.

Pass it as per the docs `functionName($variableName);` rather than `functionName(&$variableName)`

A function called with an `&$` parameter will now generate a warning, which can be suppressed, but is still a depreciated way to call.

Comment: "`shouldn't`"? What do you mean to say?

Comment: Did you intend to answer to this comment here instead of answering on DaveRandom's by mistake? The question I directed at him is in no way connected to the answers you've given above. I know what `call-by-reference` means, and I'm aware what the differences between `call-site` and `declaration-site` are. If I wasn't I would have asked (apart from the fact it's already explained in the answers.) The thing is, you say `shouldn't`, without any further explanation. It would be nice to know, why you advise against that.

Comment: @phant0m Depending on the version of PHP you have installed, it might still get through without generating errors, but is has now been depreciated and will generate warnings on current versions of PHP - but it seems you already know that. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, that's what you wanted to say. I suggest you work that into your post. Note: `The function is be enough.` doesn't make sense grammatically and I can't really guess what it should mean either ;)

Comment: @phant0m Ammended the answer, please excuse my *drunkish* :)

Answer (score 0):

Well consider a code below, This may not answer your question but a good example to understand the referenced variable.

```
<?
$variable="this is some test";

$refvariable = &$variable;
$nvariable = $variable;
$variable ="This IS ANOTHER VARIABLE STRING";

echo "Referenced Variable=".$refvariable;
echo "<bR>Normal Variable=".$nvariable;
```

?>
In simple words, above $nvariable is the normal variable, when its echoed it takes the value of $variable set initially. Now consider $refvariable which is referenced variable, it takes the latest value of $variable. 
Hope above example help you understand.